# how do you create a .c file in Visual Studio 2017 Professional

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

I am extremely new to programming and have found that a good majority of my mentors use Visual Studio to code in C.

I would like to get an early start using SAMS C Programming.

Can anyone please tell me how to create a .c file in VS 2017?  I am only able to create a .cpp file at this time.

Thanks

Comment: just save it with a .c extension.

Comment: rename the file and edit the extension so it's "file.c" instead of "file.cpp"

Comment: As OldProgrammer said, just create a code file and write the extension when you specify the filename. However, be warned that Visual Studio comes with a strange thing that somehow remotely resembles C. But there are situations where a perfectly valid C code will bring Visual Studio warnings, forcing you into bad practices. It's worth considering a different Editor / IDE with a fully standard compliant C compiler.

Comment: Thank you all! I changed the file ext. To .c when I had saved and when I had reopened the file my code was gone. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: I defeat those "strange" MSVC things with these three lines in each source file before any `#include` statements: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS \ #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE \ #define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE`.

Comment: Thanks @crunchy tried again and workes.

Thanks all!

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker: False on all accounts. Visual Studio has always had a dedicated C compiler. Modern Visual Studio C compiler is a highly respected C compiler with C99 support. Overwhelming majority of desktop C and C++ development for *all* target platforms today is done in Visual Studio under Windows.

Comment: @llama_lemons **I am extremely new to programming...** I will advice not to develop( code ) with IDE's for now, you could use simple text editor like `sublime text`, `Notepad` or any of your choice. This will hep you to master fundamental concepts that will otherwise be coded for you by an IDE.

Comment: Visual Studio does not now and has never fully supported the C99 standard. They in fact said as much in 2012, and as far as I know have not changed their stance: "We do not plan to support ISO C features that are not part of either C90 or ISO C++". Let me know when you can compile the Linux kernel with a Microsoft product; then I might change my stance.

Answer (score 2):

What you most likely actually want to do is create a project. Go to File-> New-> Project. Most likely, the first programs you will write are console applications (meaning they appear on that screen that resembles an old computer monitor, or what some computer screens look like when booting). If you want to create a console application, go from Project to Visual C++-> Windows Desktop-> Windows Console Application. Ignore any additional pop-up windows and just keep clicking continue. A file called main.cpp will automatically be generated. This is the file you will want to use for your code examples (but DO NOT DELETE the `#include "stdafx.h"` line, even if your example code does not have it).

Visual Studio compiles both .c and .cpp files as C++ by default. C++ has nearly everything that C has, but may take longer to compile when dealing with huge projects. If you want to use strictly C with no C++, then go to Project (a separate project tab on the same toolbar as the file tab -- it isn't within the file tab)-> ProjectName(Your Project Name) Properties-> Configuration Properties-> C/C++-> Advanced and select "Compile As". You should see a square with a upside-down "^" in it. Click that and select "Compile as C Code (/TC)". The "/TC" is just what you would type in if you were using command-line arguments instead of the convenient window that appears for you to modify everything. Finally, rename main.cpp to main.c.

Since you're learning C, I would also like to mention that I started making a [C tutorial](http://programcode.net/c-programming-tutorial.htm) on my web site (and if anybody else also happens to see this post and the tutorial, criticize the tutorial as harshly as you can in the comments below).

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer! The link to your C tutorial seems to be broken btw.

Answer (score 1):

If you are truly interested in learning to program in C, then leave the VS Code IDE for later and learn to [Build C/C++ code on the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line). VS provides a reasonably good compiler (`cl.exe`) and pre-configured command line (command prompt) windows to build both 32 and 64 bit applications.

The benefit to using the command line is learning what the compiler options are and what they actually do. Simply open a VS command line window and type `cl /help`. The compiler will list all options along with a short description. There are a great number of resource for command line building that can be accessed through the link above.

A second benefit is you can rapidly compile all your beginning C examples without worrying about projects, etc.. Just `cl /nologo /Wall /Ox /Foname.o /Fename.exe /Tc name.c` and you are done. (you will want to suppress unneeded warning with individual `/wdXXXX` options where `XXXX` is the warning to suppress) 50 Times faster than using the IDE.

Once you are proficient in using the command line, you will have a much easier time transitioning to the IDE -- because you can properly configure the IDE with the appropriate options for your build and you will know what the IDE is doing under the hood (or should be doing under the hood)

Answer (score 0):

Click on File, Choose Project --> Visual C++ --> Windows Desktop and under Windows desktop Choose Windows desktop wizard and give project name in the bottom then click on OK. a pop of Windows Desktop Project will come, check empty project and uncheck all options.then click on OK after that in the right side along with your project name more options will come..right lick on source file-> add -> new items -> choose c++ plus file but in bottom give file with extension .c..and you are done .enjoy coding

Comment: I seem to recall also having issues with C code in Visual Studio if I did not turn off pre-compiled headers

Project->properties->C/C++->Precompiled Headers

change the first line to "Not Using Precompiled Headers"